# Ajax function doesn't work with select2-drop-mask element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, erp

I need your assistance concerning a dev I'm doing for the ERP Dolibarr.
In the ERP you can create a new offer (with a classic form). In this form, you can define the customer name, the customer reference, the payment mode etc... I need to fill "automatically" those inputs with informations that I export from another already created offer. For eg, if my offer 1 has TOTO as customer, I can choose the offer 1, then the customer name, and when I validate the input in my new offer is filled with the value "Toto".

For that purpose I've used and ajax function:

```
$('#exportToNewPropal').on('click', function () {
    //alert("j'ai cliqué sur le bouton !");
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'propal.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: "propalId=" + $('#propalSource').val() + "&propalOption=" + $('#propalOption').val(),

        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.table, function (index, value) {
                var valueName = value.nameElt;
                switch ($("[Name=" + valueName + "]").prop('tagName')) {
                    case "SELECT":
                        console.log("c'est un select");
                        console.log("Le name de l'input select est " + valueName);
                        console.log("La valeur de l'input select est " + value.value);
$('select[Name=' + valueName + ']').val(value.value);
                        break;
                    case "TEXTAREA":
                        console.log("c'est un textarea");
                        console.log("Le name de l'input est " + valueName);
                        console.log("La valeur de l'input est " + value.value);
                        $('textarea[Name=' + valueName + ']').val(value.value);
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log("c'est un input");
                        console.log("Le name de l'input est " + valueName);
                        console.log("La valeur de l'input est " + value.value);
                        $('input[Name=' + valueName + ']').val(value.value);
                        break;
                }

            });
        }
    })
});
```

My problem is that one of the input I have to fill with information is a select in which you can make searches, and for that one only my code is not working.

Here's the HTML from the ERP :

```
<div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox select2-drop-active" style="left: 512.5px; width: 100px; top: 254.438px; bottom: auto; display: block;" id="select2-drop">   
<div class="select2-search">       
<label for="s2id_autogen1_search" class="select2-offscreen"></label>       <input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-1" id="s2id_autogen1_search" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-24">   
</div>   
<ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-1">
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable select2-highlighted" role="presentation">
<div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-24" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span></div></li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
<div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-25" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span>TEST</div></li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
<div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-26" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span>TIERS1</div></li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation">
<div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-27" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span>TIERS2</div></li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable" role="presentation"><div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-28" role="option"><span class="select2-match"></span>TIERS3</div></li></ul></div>
```

## EDIT

Here are the diferent steps I'm doing to get my data:
First, on my page card.php, I'm getting the list of my offers with a Dolibarr implemented function:

Page card.php:

```
$list = $object->liste_array();
    function func($x){
        return $x;
    }
    $listPropal = array_map(func, $list);
```

Then I add a line in the offer to add the possibility of choosing info from a different offer, based on my list of offers > $listPropal:

Page card.php:

```
 print '<tr><td>Proposition source</td><td colspan="2"><select name="propalSource" id="propalSource">';
    print '<option value="0" selected>&nbsp;</option>';
    foreach($listPropal as $elements){
       print '<option value="' . $elements['id']. '">' . $elements['ref'] . '</option>';
    }
    print '</select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select 

name="propalOption" id="propalOption">
    <option value="0">&nbsp</option>
    <option value="ref_client">Référence client</option>
    <option value="fk_soc">Tiers</option>
    <option value="fin_validite">Durée de validité</option>
    <option value="fk_cond_reglement">Conditions de règlement</option>
    <option value="fk_mode_reglement">Mode de règlement</option>
    <option value="fk_input_reason">Origine</option>
    <option value="fk_availability">Délai de livraison</option>
    <option value="fk_shipping_method">Méthode d’expédition</option>
    <option value="date_livraison">Date de livraison</option>
    <option value="note_public">Note publique</option>
    <option value="note_private">Note privée</option>
    <option value="type_presta">Type de prestation</option>
    <option value="agence">Agence</option>
    <option value="margin_rate_service">Taux de marge service</option>
    <option value="margin_rate_product">Taux de marge produit</option>
    </select>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="exportToNewPropal" type="button" class="button" value="Valider">';
```

My ajax function calls the propal.php page in which I've a made an associative array between the name of my elements into the database and the input name and I send in case of success to my ajax function the name of my input ("nameElt\":\"{$array[$propalOption]}\"), the attribute of my input (\"{$propalOption}\", \"value\") and its value ("value\" : \"{$list_propal[0][$propalOption]}\").

Page propal.php:

```
$propalId = GETPOST('propalId');
$propalOption = GETPOST('propalOption');

$list_propal = $propalSource->liste_propal($propalId);

//Tableau associatif: nom dans la base de données => name de l'input
$array = array(
    'ref_client' => 'ref_client' , 
    'fk_soc' => 'socid',
    'fin_validite' => 'duree_validite',
    'fk_cond_reglement' => 'cond_reglement_id',
    'fk_mode_reglement' => 'mode_reglement_id',
    'fk_availability' => 'availability_id',
    'fk_shipping_method' => 'shipping_method_id',
    'date_livraison' => 'date_livraison',
    'note_public' => 'note_public',
    'note_private' => 'note_private',
    'fk_input_reason' => 'demand_reason_id',
    'margin_rate_service' => 'margin_rate_service',
    'margin_rate_product' => 'margin_rate_product'
);
  // IF SUCCESS SEND TO AJAX:
    echo "{ \"table\": [";
    if (array_key_exists($propalOption, $list_propal[0])){
        echo "{ \"nameElt\":\"{$array[$propalOption]}\",\"attribute\": \"{$propalOption}\", \"value\" : \"{$list_propal[0][$propalOption]}\" }";
    } else {
        echo "{\"correspondance liste option\":aucune}";
    }
    echo "]}";
```

This code is working, meaning I fill my input with the good values for all except the one with the particular select (see its html above).

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what your goal is and what goes wrong... Are you getting the right value logged into console? What does data contain? Have you noticed in the SELECT case there is no assignment to any element? Also, could you properly format the HTML over multiple lines?

Comment: @Lily How do you know it's not working?? <- Perhaps the answer to that question should be included in your post... simply saying 'it don't work' isn't helping anyone, is it? What part of the select **specifically** isn't working?

Comment: Sorry I've edited for the missing code of the select, my copy didn't work for this part. @ProEvilz: by "not working" I mean that I can fill all my inputs except for the one I put the HTML above. All my inputs/selects and texteras do work (the info I want to export is well filled in the good inputs), but for this one nothing happened. It seems that it's because it's a special select. I Hope it's much clearer now...

Comment: `"I can fill all my inputs except for the one I put the HTML above"` - How do you know you can't fill it? Have you tried? Does it not let you click on it? What happens when you type inside of it.. does the text not appear on your screen? What do you mean?

Comment: All we know so far is that you have a `select` element that "don't work" and that you have an `input` that you "can't fill".

Comment: I've edited my post and add explanations of what I do and all my code. Is it clearer to you ?

Answer (score -1):

So, from what I understood, that ajax returns data relative to another order. Your goal is to insert this data into the various inputs in the current form - but the select is not working...

If that's the case, the first thing that I'd like to highlight, is that in `case "SELECT"` you're not doing any assignments, just logging! In the other case statement you are...

Comment: This is a **comment** and just be posted as such. This is not an answer or solution to the problem.

Comment: So you're telling me that "add the input assignment" is not an answer? If the OP didn't write all of his code is not my fault :)

Comment: @FabioLolli No, it's a pretty poor answer. It would be better as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

It would be good to explain a bit more step by step what you do to data that you get from ajax call. From what you have written I think you want to do this:

1. Data from ajax call need to be populated in input fields that already exist on the form and have unique names
2. When you get select elements you dont need to populate select 2 classes just clear the current select element and place all options inside it.
3. For all select elements you need to apply select2 again to that element which will initialise it and allow search etc as well.

If you are getting html for select 2 in your ajax it might be better to just pickup li values and their names or use value as name to create new select.

Comment: @ProEvilz The ajax call is already done, the select2 is already available to be applied. I dont think these steps are just comments. If you follow them and use the code posted by OP the solution is there. Its not generalisation, the comment is "apply the select2 library on your input" the above is an answer and it does not have to include code because OP has all the correct code available to them.

Comment: @  Farrukh Subhani, thanks for your answer. I've edited my post and tried to give you the steps I follow, hope it's clearer for you. I didn't get your solution though, could you be more explicit please ?

Comment: @Lily thanks for the update you have put in steps till you have got ajax build up. Can you then paste the ajax response you get on page and also what do you do with that ajax response on your page. When you obtain options from server can you see them in html. if you can then paste it in your question. You need to reapply select2 on that element after its populated with options at finish of ajax request.

Comment: @Farrukh Subhani, sorry for the late answer but my customer has changed his mind about what to do and I had to quickly answer to his new wish. I don't need to do the purpose of my post here anymore but I really thank you for your time and your help. When I get the chance I will try to apply your advice for resolving this issue.